# java multithread loop with collecting results

Tags: java, multithreading, loops

sorry for limited code, as i have quite no idea how to do it, and parts of the code are not a code, just an explanation what i need. The base is:

```
arrayList<double> resultTopTen = new arrayList<double();
arrayList<double> conditions = new arrayList<double(); // this arrayList can be of a very large size milion+, gets filled by different code

double result = 0;

for (int i = 0, i < conditions.size(), i++){   //multithread this

loopResult = conditions.get(i) + 5; 

   if (result.size() < 10){
      resultTopTen.add(loopResult);
   }
   else{
      //this part i don't know, if this loopResult belongs to the TOP 10 loopResults so far, just by size, replace the smallest one with current, so that i will get updated resultTopTen in this point of loop. 

   }
}
```

- loopResult = conditions.get(i) + 5; part is just an example, calculation is different, in fact it is not even double, so it is not possible simply to sort conditions and go from there.
- for (int i = 0, i < conditions.size(), i++) part means i have to iterate through input condition list, and execute the calculation and get result for every condition in conditionlist, Don't have to be in order at all.
- The multithreading part is the thing i have really no idea how to do, but as the conditions arrayList is really large, i would like to calculate it somehow in parallel, as if i do it just as it is in the code in a simple loop in 1 thread, i wont get my  computing resources utilized fully. The trick here is how to split the conditions, and then collect result. For simplicity if i would like to do it in 2 threads, i would split conditions in half, make 1 thread do the same loop for 1st half and second for second, i would get 2 resultTopTen, which i can put together afterwards, But much better would be to split the thing in to as many threads as system resources provide(for example until cpu ut <90%, ram <90%). Is that possible?

Comment: Is it really *that* hard to write code examples correctly? It’s only about a few characters having the wrong case and some missing `>` characters, but the whole code yells an “I don’t care” to the reader, which isn’t the right attitude when asking for help…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parallel stream of Java 8.

```
static class TopN<T> {

    final TreeSet<T> max;
    final int size;

    TopN(int size, Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.max = new TreeSet<>(comparator);
        this.size = size;
    }

    void add(T n) {
        max.add(n);
        if (max.size() > size)
            max.remove(max.last());
    }

    void combine(TopN<T> o) {
        for (T e : o.max)
            add(e);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Double> conditions = new ArrayList<>();
    // add elements to conditions
    TopN<Double> maxN = conditions.parallelStream()
        .map(d -> d + 5)    // some calculation
        .collect(() -> new TopN<Double>(10, (a, b) -> Double.compare(a, b)),
            TopN::add, TopN::combine);
    System.out.println(maxN.max);
}
```

Class `TopN` holds top n items of T.

This code prints minimum top 10 in `conditions` (add 5 to each element).

Answer (score -1):

Let me simplify your question, from what I understand, please confirm or add:

Requirement: You want to find top10 results from list called conditions.

Procedure: You want multiple threads to process your logic of finding the top10 results and accumulate the results to give top10.

Please also share the logic you want to implement to get top10 elements or it is just a descending order of list and it's top 10 elements.

Comment: Yes, i need to do some calculation for every member of condition list, return result. Then i wan't to get top10results list, which will be updated after every calculation - every new result done from conditions list.

Procedure: Yes, i need threads to split the condition list somehow, so multiple results can come at the same time

Logic: as the result is double, let's say the top10 are simply top10 doubles by value.

(calculation is just an example, i cannot get around iterating through list, by simply sorting the list and adding 5)